# IOS Swift: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
import SpriteKit

let BallCategoryName = "ball"
let PaddleCategoryName = "paddle"
let BlockCategoryName = "block"
let BlockNodeCategoryName = "blockNode"

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)

        // 1. Create a physics body that borders the screen
        let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)

        // 2. Set the friction of that physicsBody to 0
        borderBody.friction = 0

        // 3. Set physicsBody of scene to borderBody
        self.physicsBody = borderBody


        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
        ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(10, -10))

         }
}
```

On this line of code:

`let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as SKSpriteNode`

I get this error:

> "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Why?

Running Xcode 
Version 6.4 (6E35b)

Comment: Are you sure you have childNode with that name ? to me it seems like there is no children and that cuases exception.

Comment: Test it at runtime via `if let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as?SKSpriteNode { /* it's a ball SpriteNode :) but probably won't get called because the cast fails :( */ }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for init ball :

```
let ball : SKSpriteNode = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as SKSpriteNode
```

Let me know if you find any issue.

Thanks

Comment: like said NickCatib maybe childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName)  is nil so check if it's nul before initialize ball.